# Using mongodump with an auth enabled mongodb server

Tags: linux, backup, database-administration, mongodb, database-backup

I'm trying to do a daily backup of my mongodb server (auth enabled) using the mongodump tool.

mongodump provides two parameters to set the credentials:

```
-u [ --username ] arg   username
-p [ --password ] arg   password
```

Unfortunately they don't provide any parameter to read the password from stdin. Therefore everytime I run this command, everyone on the server can read the password (e.g. by using ps aux).

The only workaround I have found is stopping the database and directly accessing the database files using the --dbpath parameter.

Is there any other solution which allows me to backup the mongodb database without stopping the server and without "publishing" my password?

I am using Debian squeeze 6.0.5 amd64 with mongodb 1.4.4-3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, since [this request](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1129) was implemented, the password on the command line is obscured (though there is a caveat about a short window before the obscuring code kicks in).  Have you tried specifying an empty string as the password (`-p ""`), you should then be prompted for a password, which I think is the behavior you are looking for.